# Designing a special 4-bit counter with flip flops

Tags: flipflop, counter, reset

This is a normal design of 4-bit counter using D flip-flops
[image]

The outputs Q0 to Q3 are connected to diodes. I want to modify this counter in such a way that it follows the following counting sequence and that it could be set back to 9 asynchronously (maybe through the Reset and Preset inputs of the flip-flops?) anytime.
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What are your restrictions? The straight-forward way will be to add a function mapping from Q to the desired outputs.

Comment: Only the restrictions I mentioned in the topic. Can you explain more how a mapping function should look like ?

Comment: I just went through [a similar process](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/437393/38098) for someone else here. Didn't include the async reset, though. Used TFF instead of DFF.

Comment: Thank you that looks helpful, I will read it throughly. One of my restrictions is to use DFFs though.

Comment: @asisgh this is basically a state machine, map out the states and the state outputs.

Comment: as far as I can understand, it should be done through KV maps as @jonk mentioned. I hope someone could give me a detailled approach

Comment: @laptop2d that, but you could also consider it a thing that every clock adds +3 mod 16 (and the mod 16 comes for free, if you think about it). Anyway, your state machine consideration and the logic that comes out of the adder idea should be identical in the end, probably at least.

Comment: @anisgh Pretty sure that understanding KV maps is exactly what you should be learning in that course you're taking, so the shortest way to success is learning how KV maps and flip flop implementations are related; there's no shortcut that we can offer! We could only re-write one of the thousand articles you'll find online on that topic and post it as an answer here – and that would be no better than letting you read that article on your own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple table provides what's needed:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Beginning State} & \text{Ending State}\\\\
  {\begin{array}{cccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  1&1&0&0\\
  1&1&1&1\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  1&0&0&0\\
  1&0&1&1\\\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  1&0&1&0\\
  1&1&0&1\\
  1&1&1&0\\
  \end{array}} &
  {\begin{array}{cccc}
  D_D & D_C & D_B & D_A\\\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  1&1&0&0\\
  1&1&1&1\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  1&0&0&0\\
  1&0&1&1\\
  0&0&0&0\\\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  \end{array}}
\end{array}$$

Now the four K-map tables.

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
D_D&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&0&x&0&0\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&1&x&1\\
Q_D\: Q_C&1&x&0&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&1&1&0&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
D_C&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&0&x&1&1\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&0&x&0\\
Q_D\: Q_C&1&x&0&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&0&1&0&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
D_B&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&x&1&0\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&0&x&0\\
Q_D\: Q_C&1&x&1&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&1&0&0&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
D_A&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&x&0&1\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&0&x&1\\
Q_D\: Q_C&1&x&0&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&1&0&0&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

Let's start with \$D_A\$ and just follow along to see how I changed the \$x\$ values. Here we get: \$D_A=\overline{Q_A}\$:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
D_A&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&0&0&1\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&1&0&0&1\\
Q_D\: Q_C&1&0&0&1\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&1&0&0&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

Next is \$D_B\$. Again, spot my changes to \$x\$. See that: \$D_B=\overline{Q_A}\:\overline{Q_B}+Q_C\: Q_D+Q_A\: Q_B\:\overline{Q_D}\$:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
D_B&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&0&1&0\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&1&0&1&0\\
Q_D\: Q_C&1&1&1&1\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&1&0&0&0
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

Now for \$D_C\$. Spot changes and see: \$D_C=\overline{Q_A}\:\overline{Q_B}\:Q_C+Q_A\:\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_C}+Q_B\:\overline{Q_C}\:\overline{Q_D}\$:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
D_C&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&0&1&1&1\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&1&0&0&0\\
Q_D\: Q_C&1&0&0&0\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&0&1&0&0
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

And \$D_D\$: \$D_D=\overline{Q_B}\:Q_D+ Q_C\:\overline{Q_D}\$:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
D_D&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&0&0&0&0\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&1&1&1&1\\
Q_D\: Q_C&1&1&0&0\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&1&1&0&0
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

So the equation summary from the above work is:

$$\begin{align*}
D_A&=\overline{Q_A}\\
D_B&=\overline{Q_A}\:\overline{Q_B}+Q_C\: Q_D+Q_A\: Q_B\:\overline{Q_D}\\
D_C&=\overline{Q_A}\:\overline{Q_B}\:Q_C+Q_A\:\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_C}+Q_B\:\overline{Q_C}\:\overline{Q_D}\\
D_D&=\overline{Q_B}\:Q_D+ Q_C\:\overline{Q_D}
\end{align*}$$

Just note that the above isn't the only possible arrangements. By choosing differently for the \$x\$ values, you might come up with different (but equivalent) equations. If you put in a little time formulating them in several ways, you might find a better arrangement for the final circuit (fewer gates.) But I've only so much time to apply and I'm stopping it here.

Clearly, \$D_A\$ is free and \$D_D\$ is just a mux (if allowed.) The other two will involve a little more logic. But if you wire it up, it should work.

Here's how I implemented it in [Neemann's Digital](https://github.com/hneemann/Digital):

[image]

Worked exactly as expected.

The one thing that is missing is the reset to a specific point. <s>I'll leave that to you.</s>

The async reset to 9 was simple to add. So here it is despite "leaving it to you":

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for your time and help! I have tried this myself and it doesn't seem to work properly. Diode C is always on, diode D keeps jumping between 1 and 0 and the other two are always 0.

Comment: @anisgh Works fine for me. What do you mean by "diode?"

Comment: Sorry I meant LEDs, and thank you now it's working perfectly fine. Any ideas on how to do the reset ?

Comment: @anisgh Yes. If you use DFFs with both async SET and RESET added to them, you can simply wire up your reset control line to the appropriate SET or RESET of them. For a synchronous reset, you can insert a set of muxes prior to each D input. The select input to the muxes would decide whether or not the usual normal state is applied or if a hard-coded binary pattern is selected.

Comment: I can't seem to really understand how the SET and RESET inputs exactly work.. I don't need a synchronous reset, I just need a reset so that when pressed it gets back to 9 regardless of the clock, if you have some time, can you please modify the circuit above to do that? it would help me understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: @anisgh Are you sure you can't work it out? It's just using DFFs with async clear and set pins. You bring the set lines from the leftmost DFF and the rightmost DFF to your RESET line and also bring the clear lines from the inner two DFFs to that RESET line. That's all there is to it. This is the simple part. No tables. No working out optimized logic. If you can't work this out, then the above where I tried to teach you an approach won't help you much, either.

Comment: ok what about the remaining clear and set inputs?

Comment: @anisgh Check the datasheet (or the simulator you are using.) They should be ***inactive***. (Either grounded, if that's inactive, or else tied high, if that's inactive.)

Comment: Thank you very much! you are the best! I have learned a lot of things because of you. I still have one more question concerning seven segment displays, can I keep wasting your time and ask you?

Comment: here is my question [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/437779/display-4-bit-counter-on-7-segment-display)

Comment: Please keep in mind that we prefer not to give full answers to "homework" questions; instead, we provide guiding hints that lead the OP to the solution. This results in a much better learning experience.

Comment: @Dave Please keep in mind that theory illustrated through the light of concrete expositions of example problems benefit large numbers of silent but serious readers. This results in a much better *total* learning experience.

Comment: But you didn't describe the theory at all, you just worked out the OP's specific problem. Not helpful. And your "large numbers of silent readers" is purely hypothetical, while you've done a very real disservice for this actual user.

Comment: @DaveTweed It does illustrate a theory quite clearly. One that can be adduced by reading through it, in fact. And it will increase the total learning available to all reading this site. Do you really want this debate to play out in comments? Just curious.