# Asynchronous Sequencial circuit homework problem

Tags: boolean-algebra

i have some problem with this homework, i cant figure out how to continue the project.
I would be grateful if you could help me (Sorry for my bad english)

"Given the table in the figure, continue the project of a sequencial circuit."

So now i need to convert A,B,C etc with 000, 001, 010. Then write the circuit with the logic combination of the next state x1,x2? Is it right?

[image]

Comment: Present state (A to H) with x1 & x2 to produce next state & z.

Comment: x1 & x2 are the input states 00 01 11 10 (Kmap addressing).  s is state (3 bits) and z is output.

Comment: I may attempt an answer later. But if and until then, you might look at [offset sequence counter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/437393/38098) and [limited mod-3 counter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/437750/38098) for some possible thoughts about approaches to consider.

Answer (score 0):

> So now i need to convert A,B,C etc with 000, 001, 010. Then write the
>   circuit with the logic combination of the next state x1,x2? Is it
>   right?

Yes. You have eight possible states, i.e. you need at least three bits/boolean values to uniquely identify the current state.

You can basically assign any three-bit combination you like to each of the states, as long as they are unique.

Then the table defines a logic function which takes as input the current (three-bit) state (s1,s2,s3) and (x1,x2), and produces four bits of output: (s1',s2',s3',Z)

State output (s1',s2',s3') then is connected back to the current state input of the function.

Note that in a real circuit you must not directly connect the state outputs of different functions because all functions will then try to output some signal to the same wire at the same time and this will create a short circuit, so some mechanism is needed to disconnect outputs of non-active states.

Comment: Thank you for all your help
Is the procedure for making the circuit similar to this?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifFF7CS4Zd4&list=PLtHDcPFfNUXffgd152pRZttYXeoP7Pxx6&index=3

Comment: Yes, that's how you usually do it.

Comment: So i dont need to do the K-MAP because I already know the truth table of the next state (below x1,x2 on the table). So i need to write the circuit?
I can't find an exercise like that online so i'm having so much trouble 
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you don't *need* a K-map. You *can* use it to reduce the complexity of the circuit, but it's not per se necessary.