# A 4bit counter that goes up and down

Tags: circuit-design, logic-gates, counter, ripple-counter

I am kinda new to the website, I just came across it after looking for answers for such a long time. I have an assignment that asks to add an input bit to your circuit from the circuit I created that goes up my sequence of 3 up to 15 called U (for up). If U is a 1, your circuit should count up through the sequence of multiples of 3 as normal. If U is a 0, your circuit should count down through the sequence of multiples of 3 (0, 15, 12, ..., 6, 3, 0, 15, 12...). I was able to draw the truth table and the K maps both for going up and down but I don't know how to implement the input circuit. For this assignment, we use a program called Logisim. Please let me know if extra information is needed

This is the counter going up 
[image]
This is the counter going down

[image]

Comment: yes, we need more information ... please tell us what is your question

Comment: How do I make the counter go up and down? I understand that I need an input wire but what does it connect to and how?

Comment: @YousefWally Are you allowed to use any component? Or are there limitations to what you can and cannot use in Logisim? Also, note that going between 0 and 15 (either direction) isn't adding or subtracting 3, mod 3. It's adding or subtracting 1. So there is a slight complexity there. Specifically, I'm wondering if you are allowed to use a T-type FF (JK wired appropriately?) (Look at [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/437393/38098) for an example of how to proceed with your project.)

Comment: overlay the two circuits and add gates to allow switching between the two layouts. under control of the `U` line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the state transitions:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\text{State} & \text{U=1 Next} & \text{U=1 Excite} & \text{U=0 Next} & \text{U=0 Excite}\\\\
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  1&1&0&0\\
  1&1&1&1\\\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  1&0&0&0\\
  1&0&1&0\\
  1&0&1&1\\
  1&1&0&1\\
  1&1&1&0\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  1&1&0&0\\
  1&1&1&1\\
  0&0&0&0\\\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  T_D & T_C & T_B & T_A\\\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  1&1&1&1\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  1&1&1&1\\\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\\\
  1&1&1&1\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  1&1&0&0\\\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  T_D & T_C & T_B & T_A\\\\
  1&1&1&1\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  1&1&1&1\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  0&0&1&1\\\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

---

Once you have that much, all you need to do is to lay out four K-map tables for each condition of \$U\$.

For \$U=1\$ (count up):

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_D&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&0&x&0&x\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&x&x&1\\
Q_D\: Q_C&0&x&1&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&x&0&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_C&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&0&x&1&x\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&x&x&1\\
Q_D\: Q_C&0&x&1&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&x&1&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_B&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&x&0&x\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&x&x&1\\
Q_D\: Q_C&1&x&1&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&x&0&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_A&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&x&1&x\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&x&x&1\\
Q_D\: Q_C&1&x&1&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&x&1&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

For \$U=0\$ (count down):

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_D&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&x&0&x\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&x&x&0\\
Q_D\: Q_C&0&x&0&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&x&1&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_C&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&x&0&x\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&x&x&1\\
Q_D\: Q_C&1&x&0&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&x&1&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_B&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&x&1&x\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&x&x&0\\
Q_D\: Q_C&0&x&1&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&x&1&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_A&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&x&1&x\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&x&x&1\\
Q_D\: Q_C&1&x&1&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&x&1&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

You can now use those tables (fixed for errors I made above that you may catch) to develop the logic required.

---

From the above, I find:

$$\begin{align*}
T_D &= U\cdot Q_B\cdot Q_C  + \overline{U}\cdot \overline{Q_B}\cdot \overline{Q_C}\\
T_C &= U\cdot Q_B  + \overline{U}\cdot \overline{Q_A} + Q_A\cdot \overline{Q_B} \\
T_B &= U\cdot \overline{Q_A} + \overline{U}\cdot \overline{Q_C}  + Q_A\cdot Q_C \\
T_A &= 1
\end{align*}$$

---

At this point, you should be able to easily develop the logic required when using T-type FF devices.