# How can i make my mod 10 up/down counter wrap from 0 to 9 when counting down?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, counter

[image]I know there is something wrong with my reset logic because when counting down it starts from 5 and changes if i have any wires connected to the reset of the flip flops. I don't know how to fix this and have been struggling for a while now.

EDIT: this is the whole task. i wanted to make a decade counter so i could add two together and have a counter that goes from 0-99.1-99 is extra marks [Image of task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAdVG.png)

Comment: you need a counter with 4-bits of parallel inputs, those bits used to initialize the FF values upon a LOAD event.

Comment: Why not look through this [4-bit counter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/446087/38098) example and this [simple counter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/437393/38098) example, for starters. Might provide some ideas.

Comment: Can't i achieve the same thing with what i already have though? I have made another one with parallel inputs but that one has other problems. https://i.imgur.com/KYFxBKy.png

Comment: @jonk One idea that comes to mind is using a NAND gate to act as the input of the first FF.  I will play around with NAND gates some more, i have some idea on how to proceed now. I wont need to change anything with my direction change will I?  Also the K-map tables are something i have not learnt and are a hard to follow

Comment: Well, the idea of laying out the starting value and the next value, listing what changes between them, is one approach that "just works." It's not the only approach. You should use what works for you and since I don't know what you don't know, it is hard for me to suggest a direction. I was only hoping. Best is to use what you do know. So feel free. And if you have an idea, that's good!

Comment: I'd like to say I've made progress but i haven't. I noticed every Q' output is on when the counter is at 0000 and that when it wraps back to 1111 all Q outputs are on instead. I know i can do something with that i just cant figure it out how to wire it right.

Comment: Have you examined the 74169 or 74191 schematics, for example? Your situation is simpler. In any case, you've only told me what you don't know how to use (k maps for example) but haven't told me what you do know about. So all I can do right now is use ideas you say you are unfamiliar with. A waste of both our times. I need to know what mental tools you do have to apply here.

Comment: Step 1: validate the logic very carefully at schematic level: Step 2, validate the actual wiring very carefully in the prototype. Pro-tip make sure you have capacitors on all IC's in your prototype placed close from VCC to GND. We can't help with step 2, really, but if you post a photograph of your actual circuit, someone might notice something or have some useful suggestions.

Comment: Basically all i have been taught in my computer systems course are basic flips flops, registers and ripple counters. Nothing about k maps or any way to plan out a circuit. Just the very very basic fundamentals of using Logisim. All the info you have given me has helped me understand more and i will give it another try

Comment: @Xaero Where do you find yourself first getting stuck reading what I wrote? For example, when looking at the wide table I provided, do you find the ideas there difficult? Or is it pretty obvious to you how I laid out the table? The excitation columns are simply **1** where the bits changed and **0** otherwise. I hope you can see that much easily enough. (I also included the illegal value rows and used ***x*** to indicate 'don't care'.)

Comment: I can follow the logic its just the whole concept to me is new as i have never seen or used tables like what you wrote to plan out a circuit. I am currently working on the circuit again. I will update  on my progress soon. Your help has been great

Comment: @Xaero Would you be willing to download and install [Neemann's DIGITAL program](https://github.com/hneemann/Digital)? It's much better than Logisim (my opinion.) If you decide to do so, you can then also download this [example to test out](http://www.infinitefactors.org/schematics/4bitUpDownCtr.dig) which simulates this [schematic](http://www.infinitefactors.org/schematics/EESE291.png). The point of all this is that it sounds like you have been asked to guess your way forward -- like "hunt and peck." But haven't been provided a good process to get from the beginning to the end.

Comment: @jonk i am very willing to download it and simulate it. You are right that this task has been a very tedious task to do myself. I was given this task only 3 weeks into the course and the only reason why i even know what a decade counter is, is because i have been looking up circuits that can help me with another task. I have updated the main post to show you what the whole task is. I am so grateful for your help with this

Comment: @Xaero First off, it looks like the assignment says 1-99 and not 0-99. Second, you've changed the question, now. Implementation will require 7 TFFs and a different set of tables to work out the logic if you want to do this all in "one go." Alternately, you can do what is done in the 7400 series devices, which is to break this into two pieces, each the same, but provide a ripple clock (which behaves a little differently depending on count direction) so you can chain two of them together.

Comment: I should mention that because everyone in class was finding it hard to make a counter 1-99. A 0-99 will be accepted and bonus points for anyone with a 1-99. I really wanted to work on a solution myself that's why i just wanted to make a decade counter using reset logic. I figured if i had a working 0-9 up/down counter i could combine two of them and get a 0-99 counter. I am not very comfortable with asking for outside help, but my tutors have given me nothing. Just vague responses like, there is something wrong with the reset logic.

Comment: @Xaero If you chain up two of them you'll need a ripple carry out and probably an "enable" input, as well. These are found in the 74160-74163 devices. You should examine their logic.

Comment: @jonk thanks jonk for all the help but at the end of the day i really just wanted to get my own circuit to work. I know all i need to do is fix my reset logic even though using it is bad. I will carry on by myself. The 0-99 counter is for another question not this one.

Comment: @Xaero No problem. Your approach wasn't clear to me. And I only offer answers that are designed for a broad audience and not necessarily only the OP. I'm happy with my addition and hopefully it may help others. I'm sorry it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

A toggle-FF (TFF) are just master-slave JK FFs with their JK-inputs tied together. (You probably already know that much.) These toggle their outputs if the tied input is **1** and don't toggle their outputs if the tied-input is **0**. It's pretty simple to just list out the starting state, the ending state (after one clock event), and then find the bit changes. The bits that change will need a **1** applied and the bits that don't change will need a **0** applied. Not conceptually complicated, at all.

So let's take a look at the up/down counter table with the starting states, ending states, and the transitions needed in each case:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\text{State} & \text{U/D=1 Next} & \text{U/D=1 Excite} & \text{U/D=0 Next} & \text{U/D=0 Excite}\\\\
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  1&0&0&0\\
  1&0&0&1\\\\
  1&0&1&0\\
  1&0&1&1\\
  1&1&0&0\\
  1&1&0&1\\
  1&1&1&0\\
  1&1&1&1\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  1&0&0&0\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  0&0&0&0\\\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  T_D & T_C & T_B & T_A\\\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  1&1&1&1\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  1&0&0&1\\\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  1&0&0&0\\\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  T_D & T_C & T_B & T_A\\\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  1&1&1&1\\
  0&0&0&1\\\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

The above table should be pretty easy to follow. The left column just shows the current state of your TFF outputs. The **U/D=1** (UP-counting) columns show you the next state that you want, together with **1**'s in the columns where you need a state change and **0**'s where you don't. The same is then also true for the following columns, where **U/D=0** (DOWN-counting.)

The excitation columns simply show a **0** in the positions where there is no change in the bit value and show a **1** in the positions where there is a change.

---

It's then very helpful to lay out four K-map tables for each condition of **U/D**.

For **U/D=1**:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_D&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&0&0&0&0\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&0&0&1&0\\
Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&0&1&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_C&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&0&0&1&0\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&0&0&1&0\\
Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&0&0&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_B&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&0&1&1&0\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&0&1&1&0\\
Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&0&0&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_A&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&1&1&1\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&1&1&1&1\\
Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&1&1&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

For **U/D=0**:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_D&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&0&0&0\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&0&0&0&0\\
Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&1&0&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_C&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&0&0&0&0\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&1&0&0&0\\
Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&1&0&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_B&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&0&0&0&1\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&1&0&0&1\\
Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&1&0&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
T_A&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&1&1&1\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&1&1&1&1\\
Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&1&1&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

Assuming I didn't make any errors above, you can now use those tables to develop the reduced logic required for each TFF toggle input.

---

For example, take a look at both \$T_A\$ tables above. There are some "don't care" values (indicated by ***x***), but all the rest are just **1**s. By substituting in **1** for all of the ***x*** (it's a "don't care" so it doesn't matter what we do in those cases), the two tables become trivial and also identical. This means we can simply state:

$$\begin{align*}
T_A &= 1
\end{align*}$$

Or, put another way, the toggle-input for the \$Q_A\$ TFF is always **1**. No logic required. Just nail it to **1** and that's done. (Something I think you already realized. But the above process we just took ***proves*** it.)

The initial circuit, before detailed consideration of what logic to add, will now look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPECEC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that **TFF BIT 0** has its toggle-input set to **1**, per the above trivial analysis for its two tables (for each condition of **U/D**.)

You can use your imagination on the remaining tables to come up with simplified logic for each. Once you have done that, the rest of the logic shouldn't be too difficult to develop. (In the above schematic I've just used a **?** at each of the remaining three TFF devices to suggest to you that the logic for these three are yet to be worked out.)

---

Enough time has passed and I may as well provide a solution now. My first step in using the k-maps is to combine the pairs and bury inside the k-map the needed state of the **U/D** input, where appropriate. In doing this, I'm allowed to choose either case or **0** or **1** for any that are marked as ***x***. So I'm looking for "obvious" ways to capture groups of 8 all the same rather than 4, if possible; or groups of 4 all the same rather than 2; etc. The more I can make the same, the better. But I'm limited, of course, for all cases that aren't ***x***. Here's what my imagination about this first step created:

[image]

\$T_A\$ is obvious, of course. But notice that I was able to keep the uninverted **U/D** state entirely in the middle and the inverted **U/D** state entirely in the left & right sides of each of the remaining three: \$T_B\$, \$T_C\$, and \$T_D\$. This means that if I set \$F_0=U/D\:\cdot Q_A + \overline{U/D}\:\cdot \overline{Q_A}\$ then I get:

[image]

Obviously, this is wrong for all three cases I need to deal with. But it is a long stride in the right direction. Further, it only requires two NAND gates and one OR gate to achieve:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYTqfp.png)</sup>

By further inspection of each of refining each of \$T_B\$, \$T_C\$, and \$T_D\$ in the context of this new signal, \$F_0\$, I came up with the following design using the obvious (4) TFFs, plus (6) 2-in NAND, (6) 2-in OR, and (6) 2-in AND gates. You should be able to achieve something of that order of complexity, or better. (I didn't squander too much imagination on this and I'm sure someone can improve my choices.) The following comes from a screen capture where I placed and tested the above ideas under Neemann's DIGITAL (free) software.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your counter rolls to 1111 because that's the value you're presenting its input.  On the upside, it rolls over from 9 to 0 because having a 10 asynchronously resets it via the NAND in the upper right.

You could similarly have it detect a 1111 on the output (actually, either 11xx or 1x1x should be sufficient to save gate inputs) and use that signal in a similar way to asynchronously reset bits 1 and 2, resulting in an asynchronous wrap to 1001.