# I am trying to make 3bit counter with an arbitrary sequence but it gets stuck in a loop (Proteus8)

Tags: counter, homework, proteus

I am trying to make counter for these numbers 1-7-0-2-0-4-0-1-0. But for some reason on my project it gets stuck and loops on 2 digits 0-7.

This is homework, and I only can use JK flip-flpos and logic gates.

[image: This is the circuit]

[image: And these are the Tables]

Comment: If you have 9 states, you're going to need more than 3 FFs. In particular, since you have 4 different states that display '0', you can't use the state variables to drive the display directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me suggest some thoughts to consider. First off, let's look over the states you need to output:

$$\begin{array}{c}
\text{State}\\\\
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc}
  C & B & A\\\\
  0&0&1\\
  1&1&1\\
  0&0&0\\
  0&1&0\\
  0&0&0\\
  1&0&0\\
  0&0&0\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&0&0
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

The very first thing that crosses my mind is that the first state isn't 0. But when you power-up some JK FF's, the default power-up state (upon applying a \$\overline{RESET}\$ signal) should be all zeroes. So, I'd like to avoid any \$\overline{RESET}\$ difficulties. Which means I'd like to use \$\overline{Q_A}\$ instead of \$Q_A\$ to drive the observed output.

The new table is:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Internal State} & \text{Output State}\\\\
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&1
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc}
  C & B & A=\overline{Q_A}\\\\
  0&0&1\\
  1&1&1\\
  0&0&0\\
  0&1&0\\
  0&0&0\\
  1&0&0\\
  0&0&0\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&0&0
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

Note that the reset state is perfect. Just what we want.

The next problem is all those zeroes. So let's assign the fact that if \$Q_D=1\$ then this fact alone will force the upper two bits of the output to zero. That way, we can just use \$Q_D=0\$ as an *enable* to allow the upper two FF states to pass to the output and when \$Q_D=1\$ those upper two FF states are ignored and zeroes are output, instead.

This also plays into the idea of the two "one" states you have. So the following table results, keeping in mind the states after \$\overline{RESET}\$:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Internal State} & \text{Conceptual State} & \text{Output State}\\\\
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\\\
  0&y&y&0\\
  1&1&1&0\\
  0&x&x&1\\
  1&0&1&1\\
  0&x&x&1\\
  1&1&0&1\\
  0&x&x&1\\
  0&y&y&0\\
  0&x&x&1
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  \overline{Q_D} & Q_C & Q_B & \overline{Q_A}\\\\
  1&y&y&1\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  1&x&x&0\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  1&x&x&0\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  1&x&x&0\\
  1&y&y&1\\
  1&x&x&0
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  C & B & A=\overline{Q_A}\\\\
  0&0&1\\
  1&1&1\\
  0&0&0\\
  0&1&0\\
  0&0&0\\
  1&0&0\\
  0&0&0\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&0&0
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

Here, I've assigned \$xx\$ where we have a state 0 case and \$yy\$ where there is a state 1 case. In the \$xx\$ situation, we have four 0 cases so we'll need all four permutations. But in the \$yy\$ case we only need two of four permutations.

Please note that in the \$xx\$ cases \$Q_A=1\$ and in the \$yy\$ cases \$Q_A=0\$.

Let's expand the table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Internal State} & \text{Conceptual State} & \text{Output State}\\\\
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  1&1&1&0\\
  0&0 &0&1\\
  1&0&1&1\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  1&1&0&1\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&1&1&1\\\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  1&0&1&0\\
  1&1&1&0
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  \overline{Q_D} & Q_C & Q_B & \overline{Q_A}\\\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  1&0&0&0\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  1&0&1&0\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  1&1&0&0\\
  1&1&0&1\\
  1&1&1&0\\\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  1&0&0&0\\
  1&0&1&1\\
  1&1&0&1\\
  1&1&1&0\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&1&1&1
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc}
  C & B & A=\overline{Q_A}\\\\
  0&0&1\\
  1&1&1\\
  0&0&0\\
  0&1&0\\
  0&0&0\\
  1&0&0\\
  0&0&0\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&0&0\\\\
  x&x&x\\
  x&x&x\\
  x&x&x\\
  x&x&x\\
  x&x&x\\
  x&x&x\\
  x&x&x
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

From here, you know that \$C=Q_D \cdot Q_C\$ and \$B=Q_D \cdot Q_B\$ and \$A=\overline{Q_A}\$.

Now, all you need is a transition table to provide the logic required to move from state to state. It's actually not that hard. For example, see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/467187/38098) for a possible process to get there from here.

Feel free to ask questions about the above steps or about how to proceed beyond this point towards an answer that implements the desired output.

---

## Appended Per Your Request

#### JK FF vs T FF

All JK FF can be turned into a T FF by simply wiring the J and K inputs together. This is a choice you can make on your own. The only difference might be some advantages in the combinatorial logic. If you want to go to the work of finding out, feel free. But the following table lists the only four possible cases you might care to think about:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Transition} & \text{JK FF} & \text{T FF}\\\\
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{c}
\text{start }\to\text{ end}\\\\
  0 \quad \to \quad 0\\
  1 \quad \to \quad 1\\
  0 \quad \to \quad 1\\
  1 \quad \to \quad 0
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cc}
  J & K \\\\
  0&x\\
  x&0\\
  1&x\\
  x&1
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{c}
  T\\\\
  0\\
  0\\
  1\\
  1
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

Please take a moment and carefully examine the above table until you ***fully*** understand it. You should be able to readily see why it is a correct statement of the situation.

It's a lot easier to just wire both J and K together and focus on only one control bit. But that doesn't mean you cannot lay out the fuller table using both J and K, separately. If you do, you get some "don't cares" in your final k-maps which may work to your favor with some of the logic. My modest experience is that it's not worth the extra bother for educational purposes. However, if I were doing this professionally (and two decades ago before there was super-fancy software that is free to use and can work this out in moments for you) then I probably would go to the effort. But then, I might not be using full JK FF, either, in that case. So... who knows?

Bottom line? Just pick your poison and go forward from there.

## K-Maps

The internal and conceptual states mentioned above are entirely equivalent. It really doesn't matter which you choose to work with. But for simplicity, I'd just stick with the internal states listed above to avoid confusion when talking about it.

Let's lay out the transitions:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Internal State} & \text{Excitations} & \text{Output State}\\\hline\\
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\
  \vphantom{\left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{cc}J & K\end{array} } \right.}\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  1&1&1&0\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  1&0&1&1\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  1&1&0&1\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&1&1&1\\\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  1&0&1&0\\
  1&1&1&0
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\
  \left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{cc}J & K\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x
  \end{array} } \right. &
  \left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{cc}J & K\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\
    1&x\\
    x&0\\
    x&0\\
    x&0\\
    x&1\\\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x
  \end{array} } \right. &
  \left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{cc}J & K\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\
    1&x\\
    x&0\\
    x&1\\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x
  \end{array} } \right. &
  \left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{cc}J & K\\
    0&x\\
    1&x\\
    x&0\\
    x&0\\
    x&0\\
    x&0\\
    x&1\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x
  \end{array} } \right. \\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc}
  C & B & A\\
  \vphantom{\left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{cc}J & K\end{array} } \right.}\\
  0&0&1\\
  1&1&1\\
  0&0&0\\
  0&1&0\\
  0&0&0\\
  1&0&0\\
  0&0&0\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&0&0\\\\
  x&x&x\\
  x&x&x\\
  x&x&x\\
  x&x&x\\
  x&x&x\\
  x&x&x\\
  x&x&x
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

At this point, you can map the above into the following k-maps. Anywhere you see \$x\$, it means an explicit "don't care" comes from the above table. Anywhere you see nothing at all, it means an implicit "don't care" because it's from the impossible states at the bottom of the table. The rest are, of course, explicit values:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_D\text{ }J&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&1&1&\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&0&0&0&\\
Q_D\: Q_C&&x&&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&&&x&
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_D\text{ }K&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&x&x&x&\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&x&x&\\
Q_D\: Q_C&&1&&1\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&&&1&
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_C\text{ }J&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&0&1&\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&x&x&\\
Q_D\: Q_C&&x&&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&&&0&
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_C\text{ }K&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&x&x&x&\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&0&0&1&\\
Q_D\: Q_C&&0&&1\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&&&x&
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_B\text{ }J&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&1&x&\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&1&0&x&\\
Q_D\: Q_C&&0&&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&&&x&
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_B\text{ }K&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&x&x&1&\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&x&1&\\
Q_D\: Q_C&&x&&1\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&&&0&
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_A\text{ }J&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&0&x&x&\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&1&x&x&\\
Q_D\: Q_C&&x&&1\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&&&x&
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_A\text{ }K&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&x&0&0&\\
\overline{Q_D}\:Q_C&x&1&1&\\
Q_D\: Q_C&&0&&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&&&0&
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

You should be able to work out the optimal logic for each of the J and K inputs of each of the four JK FF, now.

And please satisfy yourself about how I developed the above tables (and check my work while you are at it.)

If you do work it out well, I think you'll find needing not more than (4) AND gates and (3) OR gates, in addition to the (4) JK FF. If using 74xx series parts, perhaps (2) 7473, (1) 7408, and (1) 7432.

(You can't imagine how much of this I had to do in order to design and then wire-wrap and build the execution unit of my own CPU back circa 1974. I could only wish we had EEPROMS back then. But no luck.)

## A Final Result -- Added After OP's Homework Completed

The next step was to skim the K-Maps and try to minimize the required logic for each. Others may choose differently, but without spending more than a few minutes (and then a few more minutes to capture this picture), I came up with the following choices (red circles the "1"s and blue circles the "0"s):

[image]

This leads to the following results:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
& \text{Expression}\\\hline
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r}
  Q_D \left\{\begin{array}{c}
        \vphantom{\overline{Q_C}} J\\
        \vphantom{1} K
      \end{array}
      \right.\\
  Q_C \left\{\begin{array}{c}
        \vphantom{\overline{Q_D}\cdot\left(Q_B +\overline{Q_A}\right)} J\\
        \vphantom{Q_B} K\end{array}
      \right.\\
  Q_B \left\{\begin{array}{c}
        \vphantom{\overline{Q_A}+\overline{Q_C}} J\\
        \vphantom{Q_C+\overline{Q_D}} K\end{array}
      \right.\\
  Q_A \left\{\begin{array}{c}
        \vphantom{Q_C} J\\
        \vphantom{Q_C\cdot\overline{Q_D}} K\end{array}
      \right.
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{c}
  \left.\begin{array}{c}\overline{Q_C}\\1\end{array}\right.\\
  \left.\begin{array}{c}\left(\overline{Q_A}\, +\,Q_B\right)\,\cdot\,\overline{Q_D}\\Q_B\end{array}\right.\\
  \left.\begin{array}{c}\overline{Q_A}\,+\,\overline{Q_C}\\Q_C\,+\,\overline{Q_D}\end{array}\right.\\
  \left.\begin{array}{c}Q_C\\Q_C\,\cdot\,\overline{Q_D}\end{array}\right.
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

And then this implementation in [Neemann's Digital program](https://github.com/hneemann/Digital):

[image]

This validates the operation just simulating the basic parts on the left and using 7400 parts on the right. They both produce exactly your desired state transitions, perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But i did not get how to move forward from your example.Could you epxlain me how can i get the J and K inputs for the flipflops.

Comment: @MustafaYağızÖzduygun A T FF is just a JK with the J and K wired together. Is there a reason you cannot or do not want to use that configuration?

Comment: @m@MustafaYağızÖzduygun It's not required, of course, and the exact same approach I used for T-types works equally well if you want to expose both J and K inputs of each FF. Just follow the recipe I provided but include a column for J and a column for K instead of a column for T. I think it's more work that way. But that doesn't mean you can't do it.

Comment: This is an assigment so i have to use jkflipflops.One more thing i did not understand the way you draw the k-map.Can you explain it?

Comment: @MustafaYağızÖzduygun It's up to you how you want to arrange it. I arranged it in the traditional way, which (where possible) goes from 00, 01, 11, 10 across the top and 00, 01, 11, 10 down the left side for up to four bits. If you have fewer, say three, then you might go 00, 01, 11, 10 across the top and just 0, 1 down the side. What part of it don't you get? Have you taken a close look at the example I gave and tried to spot what I did to create it? I made it directly, just looking by eye, from the table I previously created.

Comment: For exampale when you use TD values do you write them in oder or something.Maybe just drawing one example for my circuit might better for me to understand.

Comment: @MustafaYağızÖzduygun It will have to wait, as I have other, more immediate tasks to deal with right now.

Comment: Thank you for your anser jonk.For some reason i wasn't able to make the K maps work but after i was it i kinda understood the processes and i was able the finish the circuit in time for my assigment.Again thank you for sticking with me and explaning beautifly.

Comment: @MustafaYağızÖzduygun I'm very glad to hear that! Best wishes. I suppose you can select my answer so that others won't try and add another. Saves them time.

Comment: @MustafaYağızÖzduygun Also, since your homework is finished now, I'll add a final section showing a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

When generating arbitrary sequences, it's easiest to just use a counter and a ROM. And since you have a ROM, just put the counter logic into it, too.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjx3n7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Sorry i forgot the add to part that i only can use  jk flip-flpos and logic gates.

Comment: A ROM is equivalent to logic gates (a whole bunch of NAND gates). Use your logic minimization skills to come up with a gate diagram. And I assume you know how to make an ordinary binary counter with JKFFs.

Comment: Yes i know how to make a bianry counter but i am kinda new at this.Can you elaborate on process a bit more.

Comment: Draw state diagram. Assign state values and output values to states. Minimize the resulting logic. You seem to have skipped the first two steps and gone straight to the third step.

Comment: You said that i will need more than 3ff so do i have to make this a 4 bit counter?

Comment: @MustafaYağızÖzduygun Dave completely describes the details both in his comment (which I consider already *perfect* by itself) and also in his answer. You will need four FF to cover at least 9 states. You will also need some logic for the output because you have four zeroes to generate. No escaping either point. So you want four FFs, plus some logic to transition the states, then still more logic to convert a state to the output you want. You can do all of this with FF + combinatorial logic. Easy.

Comment: @MustafaYağızÖzduygun The only complexity you have is in working out which, out of myriad possible incarnations, yields the least combinatorial logic. But all of the incarnations can work. Some will be more cumbersome than others, is all. You could just "go for it" and not worry. Or you could list out all of the permutations, develop the logic for each, and then select the "least-logic" version. But that would be "real work," in my opinion. I'd just pick a direction and go for it. Let someone else do the hard work if they wanted a minimized design. Exhaustive analysis is best left to software.

Comment: @MustafaYağızÖzduygun Personally? I'd recognize that you have four 0s, two 1s, and then 2, 4, and 7. I think you can use this fact to arrange some really interesting states that have some promise for easier logic. Seriously, this looks kind of interesting.