# A Counter Which Counts Two Different Sequences

Tags: counter, karnaugh-map

I have a question which asks me to design a counter which counts two different sequences.

The question goes like this:

Design a counter which counts 0,4,6,8,12,14. When the counter reaches 14, it is going to stop and stay like that for 3 minutes. After this 180 seconds is over, this same counter it is going to start counting like a basic up-counter (0, 1, 2,.....15) (I can design a second counter only for the 180 seconds waiting process).

I have constructed the Truth Table for the two sequences, but I am having a hard time with my Karnaugh Maps. Because sometimes I need to write two outputs for the same cell (a logical 1 and 0). For example while evaluating my J1 input there is both a logical 1 and logical 0 for the 0100 cell. I do not know how I am going to handle them. Can you help me with that? Is there any particular method? (I need to use J-K Flip Flops to design the counter).

Comment: You never did answer my question, asked in your prior question, which is why I didn't respond further there. Here, you don't say anything about the applied clock rate or the time between state 0 and state 4 and then state 6, etc. But you do talk about the hold time of 3 minutes. Why does time NOT matter in some cases but then matters once, in another case (the gap between the two sequence behaviors?) You might consider using 5 or more FFs here. But I've no idea because I don't understand ***all*** of the timing requirements and the clock rate applied.

Comment: I am deeply sorry for the inconvenience I caused to you, after a short while I asked my question, I actually corrected my mistakes. Since there was a time limit, I completed my design and all of the things were ready. However, shortly after that we received another mail from our lecturer and he changed few things on the question and extended the deadline to 17th day of this month. I am verry sorry for that.

Comment: There is going to be 6,667 seconds in between every count (state). So I thought that I would consider creating a counter which counts to 27. I do not think that I am going to run into many problems on the waiting block part. I am just having problems on changing the sequence of the counter.

Comment: You could just use 5 FFs. 16 states + 6 states = 22 states. 32 permutations handles that, just fine. Read [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/504684/38098) for such an example.

Comment: Thank you so much, I inspected it and have some couple of ideas on my mind. Will try to design the counter a few hours later. I will keep you updated here. Thank you so much again.

Comment: No problem. Hopefully, that answer can help you proceed forward and succeed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109302/discussion-between-kucar-and-jonk).

Comment: I'll assume you accidentally started a chat, for now.

Comment: Yes, I was going to give some updates and accidentally clicked chat option, sorry for that. I constructed my truth tables, I believe there are some minor mistakes which were caused by me. Because of that some values of the counter does not show up but I can see that I am going on the right direction. Thank you again.

Comment: If you post up some of your work product, it might encourage me to say something directly constructive.

Comment: https://ibb.co/dPgC6Fx
This my Truth Table for the sequence I wrote above. I constructed Karnaug Mappings according to this table; however when I simulate my circuit, it counts 00000-00100-00100-00110 and then it jumps to 00001. Then it just goes back and forth between 00110 and 00001. I know my Table is complicated, however I tried my best not to make any mistake, and I am kind of stuck at this point right now.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that. Could you include the image in your question and then spend a little time discussing your columns and rows? I'd like more explanation from you than that. For example, why don't you just work out the logic for the 0,4,6,8,12,14 counts and then work out how to use a single control line to disable that logic so that the counter works from 0 to 15, directly? It's not hard to do. So I'm curious about why you choose to do what you do, as well as how you are doing what you are doing.